# Runtime structure using reflection

Tags: go

Assume I have data model written in some sort of yaml file.

```
schema: human
type: object
properties:
    name:
        type: string
    surname:
        type: string
```

I would like to parse it, and generate structure:

```
type Human struct {
    Name string `db:"name"`
    Surname string `db:"surname"`
}
```

Is it possible to generate runtime Go struct using reflection?

Comment: If you understand C++ at all, take a look at the answer to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701382/checking-ahead-for-future-groups-when-parsing-tokens). I don't know Go, but as languages have always been generated, your best bet is defining a lexer, parser and code-generator which outputs Go, and *then* use reflection on the generated code.

Comment: @JimB Parse the file into a Go string and do reflection on it?

Comment: As @JimB already mentioned you cannot generate types at **runtime**, but you can generate code with the help of the go generate tool. See more here: https://blog.golang.org/generate

Comment: @finnrayment: reflecting on strings containing code isn't going to accomplish anything, they're still just strings. If you didn't have the types at compile time, they don't exist.

Comment: @JimB Ah ok. Was just wondering since I don't program in Go. In Java, if I create a class in reflection, I can reference it after compile time. Same with Python. Nice to know the boundaries. :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that you _can_ build a struct, but you can't define a _type_, therefor its usefulness will be limited when trying to compose it within your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can with [`reflect.StructOf`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructOf):

```
sType := reflect.StructOf([]reflect.StructField{
    {Name: "Name", Type: stringType, Tag: reflect.StructTag(`db:"name" json:"name"`)},
    {Name: "Surname", Type: stringType, Tag: reflect.StructTag(`db:"surname" json:"surname"`)},
})
sv := reflect.New(sType)
svi := sv.Interface()
b, err := json.Marshal(svi)
fmt.Printf("%s %v", b, err)
```

Prints

```
{"name":"","surname":""} <nil>
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/U4N3bbJ5n8.

But as others have said, sometimes it's better to just generate code. Reflection is kinda wonky at times, and requires a lot of precision when using it.